# How do I configure MapProxy to show only cache?

Tags: cache, mapproxy

I have local files of the already built cache.  Now I try to configure a layers which gets the cache layer and shows it, but the problem is that I can't make it ignore the original "sources" because it always asks me to specify the source and I don't want it to try get new layers from the server.

```
layers:
  - name: Earth
    title: EarthA
    sources: [eartch_cache]
caches:
  earth_cache:
    grids:[gm_flat]
    sources: []  #<- I can't do this, although I want something like that

globals:
 cache:
   base_dir: S:\CACHCE
```

It's not the whole configuration but its the important parts...

Is there any way to make MapProxy work with only cache?

I'm not familiar with MapProxy.

Comment: I'm re-opening this question in response to a flag by a user who says that they have an answer to post.

Answer (score 3):

Leaving the `sources` array empty is allowed when you specify an explicit `cache` property. The following example uses an `mbtiles` cache, but any cache format should work:

```
caches:
  local_only:
    grids: [GLOBAL_MERCATOR]
    sources: []
    cache:
      type: mbtiles
```

When you use the `local_only` cache in a layer, it will load its data from `cache_data/local_only.mbtiles` only.

I tested this with MapProxy 1.8.2, but I was unable to find the matching entry in the change log, so I don't know what the first version is that supports this feature.

#### Update

I just found the following statement [in the caches/mbtiles section in the docs](https://mapproxy.org/docs/1.13.0/caches.html#mbtiles):

> You can set the sources to an empty list, if you use an existing MBTiles file and do not have a source.

Now that version 1.13.0 is out, this applies to additional cache types, such as geopackage files and s3 sources. So the quote above does not mean it can only be done with mbtiles exclusively.